# Python 2.7: Widget Doesn't Destroy When Radiobutton is Clicked More Than Once

Tags: python, tkinter

My code shows FunctionAllocation label and two radio buttons, and once one radio button is clicked, it shows Subject ID label and its entry bar. Once return key is clicked, all widgets are destroyed and new message appears.

Everything works smoothly if radio button is clicked once. However, if I click a radio button and then click another radio button, Subject ID label and its entry bar do not disappear despite .destroy() command.

How do I make sure the widgets disappear no matter which & how many times the radio buttons are pressed?

Thank you so much in advance!

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    #Initial Settings
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.radioButtons()

    #Place Initial Buttons
    def radioButtons(self):
        #Variable to tie two radio buttons
        self.tieVar1 = StringVar()

        #Text before FA buttons
        self.buttonLabel1 = Label(root, text="Function Allocation:")
        self.buttonLabel1.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)

        #Two Radio FA buttons
        self.radio1 = Radiobutton(text = "FA_F", variable=self.tieVar1, value="FA1", command=lambda: self.addSubject())
        self.radio1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
        self.radio2 = Radiobutton(text = "FA_I", variable=self.tieVar1, value="FA2", command=lambda: self.addSubject())
        self.radio2.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)

    def addSubject(self):
        #Text before ID entry bar
        self.buttonLabel2 = Label(root, text="Subject ID:")
        self.buttonLabel2.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.6, anchor=CENTER)

        #ID entry bar
        self.myEntry = Entry()
        self.myEntry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=CENTER)
        self.contents = StringVar()
        self.contents.set("Sample Text")
        self.myEntry["textvariable"] = self.contents
        self.myEntry.bind('<Key-Return>', self.reset_contents)

    #Action when return key pressed after typing subject ID
    def reset_contents(self, event):
        #Delete all 
        self.buttonLabel1.destroy()
        self.buttonLabel2.destroy()
        self.radio1.destroy()
        self.radio2.destroy()
        self.myEntry.destroy()

        #Setting up new window
        self.setActions()

    def setActions(self):
        Label(text="Done!", font=("Times", 10, "bold")).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

    #Final settings to keep window open
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1000x400")
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Why do you think it's not being destroyed? Are you getting an error? Are you certain the destroy method is being called? Are you certain it's being called on the correct widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a new Label and Entry every time you click that button. However your destroy only destroys the last one created. The easiest fix is to simply check if the Label has already been created:

```
def addSubject(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'buttonLabel2'):
        return # abort this method if the Label is already created
    # rest of your method
```

Unrelated, but if you want your Radiobuttons to start in a blank state rather than a tristate, you need to initialize the StringVar like this:

```
self.tieVar1 = StringVar(value='Novel')
```